# Error importing keras backend - cannot import name has_arg

Tags: tensorflow, keras

i attempt to import keras backend to get_session as follows, but i encounter an error:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There should be no need to import the tensorflow_backend explicitly.

Look at the first lines of an example from the [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/backend/):

```
# TensorFlow example
>>> from keras import backend as K
>>> tf_session = K.get_session()
[...]
```

As long as you are using the tensorflow backend, the get_session() function should be available.